# RedCap stopaction kicks out participant without an option to continue

Tags: survey, redcap

I am gathering data for a research and for our survey we want every participant to first answer a question for us to be able to tell if they are eligible to be included in the reasearch. I've added a yes/no question with a stop action, so if the participant chooses no they'll be kicked out of the survey. However before they're kicked out theres an information box that tells them the option they've chosen is going to trigger the survey to end and gives them the chance to go back and change their answer. I'd like for them to be kicked out of the survey directly and the stop action text to be displayed.

Is this possible? If not, is it possible to change the language in which the information in the pop up box gets displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you go into Survey Settings for the Online Designer of your instrument, you can change what text appears in the information box when a participant answers a question in a way that triggers the survey stop action. I think through this, you can make it more clear the actions you want participants to take if they are not eligible to participate in the survey and or do not consent to participating.

[image: Stop Action Alternative Text]

Based off of the documentation, (https://www.utsouthwestern.edu/edumedia/edufiles/about_us/admin_offices/academic_information_services/redcap/stop-survey-actions.pdf), it seems that the workflow of how stop actions work is hard-coded and not customizable (e.g. a participant being warned that their response would close the survey and having the option to change their response).

I guess something that you could do (though it wouldn't help much because respondents could still change their response), is just make sure that branching logic only shows relevant questions when participants answer your stop action question in a certain way.

Hope this helps.